# Chrome browser cookies / redirect issue

Tags: php, google-chrome, session, cookies

I am working on a web project and I am dealing with an issue I have never came across before and was hoping someone on here might be able to assist.

## Original

My project utilizes cookies to store session/authentication information. This session handler is built in-house and not using PHP's core session handler.

When using a fresh install of Google Chrome (on up-to-date Windows 8.1), upon visiting the URL, I receive an Error 404 page. When I run this in Incognito Mode, it works properly.

On a couple occasions where I have gotten it to work in some way, refreshing the page or using the 'Back' button, then navigating further loses my cookies in Chrome and forces to login again, which brings me back to an Error 404 page.

Additionally, other browsers have been tested with (Firefox and IE 11)  and it also works properly.

Lastly, I have had another person test this on their own machine through Chrome, and they achieve the same results (fails on normal tab, passes in Incognito mode).

I would be happy to show you guys the code if I was allowed to, but unfortunately rules above my own authority allow me too. Has anyone ever ran into a similar issue with Google Chrome?

I am open to any suggestions. There are no extensions installed at this point on Google Chrome.

Thank you for any help you can provide.

### [EDIT] Update to Issue

I have managed to narrow this down to cURL returning `cURL error (35): SSL connect error` which causes my system to spit out an Error 404 page - but my issue extends beyond that considering this is only happening in Google Chrome in normal mode. How could this possibly effect PHP's cURL abilities, being that it is server-side and completely detached from the browser itself at this level?

I dug into my setting on Google Chrome, and found that "Predict network actions to improve page load performance" was **enabled**. Upon disabling this setting, I am no longer receiving this issue.

Can anyone elaborate why this enabled setting would be causing this issue in Google Chrome?

Answer (score 2):

we encountered something similar and found that our problem caused by using full URL links. Whenever we used full URL, the security kicks in and the cookies didn't stick for the another page. But when we switch using partial URL, the cookies stay and everything works correctly.  But not sure if this would fix your problem.